# How to clean install python on windows?

Tags: python

My python installation is borked :(

Normally I just nuke my OS when my python install craps out, but I am on a work machine that takes a literal day to reimage and I'd rather not get IT involved. Is there a way to totally wipe python, anaconda, and all packages installed by pip from my machine and start totally fresh?

Comment: sure, anaconda should be installed in a folder, just delete it and restart

Comment: Windows is currently recycling 4.15 GB of data...

Comment: Why and how do you know that your Python installation is borked? And why are you using anaconda? Nuking OS seems like an overkill for like a lot of problems, including this one....

Comment: just download the python, put it in some folder and in your system path give the path to python executable in that folder and it is done

Comment: There is also [portable Python](https://portablepython.com/) but It might have limited features. Last version is 2.7.6.1 (13 Apr 2014).

Comment: @Matiiss I enjoy a fresh install. Usually I just save whatever data I really need (pictures, movies, etc) to an external drive anyway, and all my code is on GitHub, so my OS doesn't really have anything but packages and programs.

Comment: Why do you think your installation of Python is borked tho? It makes little sense in the first place, unless you've messed up real bad some weird machinery or sth, idk. Also, I've heard anaconda is pretty terrible, not sure why you're using that either.

Comment: @Matiiss I tried to install a package and got an error that I couldn't resolve after two hours. Fastest way to fix it is to just nuke the install honestly.

Comment: Well, now you're going into XY problem territory, nuking installs is unreasonable in most cases, what package and what error was it? You sure it's not something related specifically to anaconda or some other environment shenanigans?